# error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have some input tag and a jquery code that calculate some numbers.

```
var sumPliche = parseFloat($('#addome').val()) + parseFloat($('#pettorale').val()) + parseFloat($('#coscia').val());

$("#sommaPliche").val(sumPliche);

var densitàCorporea = 1.10938 - (0.0008267 * $('#sommaPliche').val()) + (0.0000016 * ($('#sommaPliche').val() * $('#sommaPliche').val())) - (0.0002574 * $('#anni').val());

$("#densitaCorporea").val(densitàCorporea);

var bf = (495 / $('#densitaCorporea').val()) - 450;

$("#bf").val(bf);

var peso = parseFloat($('#peso').val());

var bf = parseFloat($('#bf').val()) / 100;

var valDaBf = (1 - bf) ;

var lbm = valDaBf * peso;

var metBasale = 370 + (21.6 * lbm);

$('#metBasale').val(parseInt(metBasale));
```

After that, I have a mysql query to insert these values into my mysql database

```
$tricipite = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['tricipite']);
$addome = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['addome']);
$soprailiaca = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['soprailiaca']);
$sottoscapolare = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['sottoscapolare']);
$ascellare = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['ascellare']);
$pettorale = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['pettorale']);
$coscia = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['coscia']);
$sommaPliche = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['sommaPliche']);
$densitaCorporea = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['densitaCorporea']);
$bf = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['bf']);
$metBasale = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['metBasale']);
$tdee = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['tdee']);
$tdeeObiett = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['tdeeObiett']);
$tdeeSett = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['tdeeSett']);

$query = "INSERT INTO `wp_misure`(`Tricipite`, `Addome`, `Soprailiaca`, `Sottoscapolare`, 
 `Ascellare`, `Pettorale`, `Coscia`, `Somma Pliche`, `Densita corporea`) VALUES 
 ('$tricipite', '$addome', '$soprailiaca', '$sottoscapolare', '$ascellare', '$pettorale', 
 '$coscia', '$sommaPliche', '$densitaCorporea')";
```

But php gives me an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '2746, '', '21322', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '70', '1.0767509400' at line 1

What does it mean?
How can I fix it?

Comment: The first step is to `echo $query` so you can look at it. It's hard to debug code you can't see.

Comment: please show the table schema as well

Comment: You are escaping 14 variables. Inserting 9 values. And the error message shows 12 values.

Comment: How can you fix it?  Learn to use parameters.  Don't munge query strings with constant values.

Answer (score 0):

I found the key to this problem. There was a mistake in the query because I wrote ''$namevariable instead of '$namevariable'. For this reason mysql showed me the error. Now everything comes in the right way.
Thank you for your support.